# Sencha Touch 2: Change the text of an HTML button in itemTpl

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

In the itemTpl for my DataView, I have the following line:

`<div class="btn" id="colorbtn" uniqueId="{id}">{[this.getColorButton(values)]}</div>`

In my listener I have the following:

```
listeners : {
element  : 'element',
delegate : '#colorbtn',
tap      : function(item, idx, el, evt) {
// gets the item you tapped
   btnId = el.getAttribute('uniqueId');
   //Ext.getCmp('colorbtn').setText('New Value');
    alert("hello "+btnId );
}
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to get the button with `Ext.getCmp` and set new text, but this is throwing the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setText' of undefined`. Is there a way to achieve what I'm after?

Comment: Why are you using Ext.getCmp('colorBtn') when you already have a reference to the button via el? Try el.setText('New Value')

Comment: I have no idea why that didn't occur to me. Unfortunately I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. It seems the appropriate thing would be `el.setHtml` but that throws the same error.

Comment: Does the btnId in alert("hello "+btnId ); actually return the uniqueId or is it blank (null)?

Comment: It returns the correct ID.

Comment: OK then try the following:  Ext.get(el).setHtml('New Value') ;

Comment: @synapze Your a life saver! It works great. Go ahead and submit an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the element variable returned in your event with Ext.get(), this will retrieve Ext.dom.Element object. Then you can use the available methods for Ext.dom.Element.

Example:

```
 Ext.get(el).setHtml('New Value') ;
```

Note: Automatically fixes if an object was recreated with the same id via AJAX or DOM.